# xml2js is vulnerable to prototype pollution

Tags: python, security, aws-sdk, xml2js

xml2js  <=0.4.23
Severity: high
xml2js is vulnerable to prototype pollution  - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-776f-qx25-q3cc
No fix available
node_modules/xml2js
aws-sdk  *
Depends on vulnerable versions of xml2js
node_modules/aws-sdk

2 high severity vulnerabilities

Upgraded aws-sdk npm package to latest version. But vulnerability still exists.

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. delete your `package-lock.json`,
2. add this to your `package.json`:

```
 "overrides": {
   "xml2js": "^0.5.0"
 }
```

3. reinstall the deps : `npm i`

Comment: does not work for me unfortunately

Comment: Deleting `package-lock.json` should not be done lightly. Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: `0.6.2` also worked for me. https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2js

Answer (score 3):

Given answers work well for hiding the error but you will face errors while making a development build or apk of the app.
Following steps helped me solve the issue:

1. Search for xml2js in package-lock.json file
2. You will find xml2js version like this

   `"xml2js" : "0.4.23"`

You need to replace `0.4.23` by `0.5.0`

```
`"xml2js" : "0.5.0"`
```

3. Run `npm install`

This will resolve the error.

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me

1. delete package-lock.json
2. delete node modules
3. `npm i xml2js`
4. add this to my package.json:

   ```
   "overrides": {
     "xml2js": "^0.5.0"   }
   ```
5. `npm i`