# How to fix "xml2js" vulnerability in npm audit report for Microsoft Office add-in packages?

Tags: office-js, package.json, office-addins, xml2js, npm-vulnerabilities

I am developing a Microsoft Office PowerPoint React add-in using various packages. I used Yeoman to start working with the example add-in. Later, I installed "antd" and "react-router-dom". However, upon running npm audit, I received a message indicating 9 high severity vulnerabilities, with the most critical being related to the xml2js package. The full audit report message is provided below. As multiple packages depend on xml2js, and there is currently no fix available for the vulnerability, I am concerned about the security of my add-in. Can you please provide steps that I can take to address this vulnerability and ensure the security of my add-in?

Thank you in advance for your help.

PD: My current environment includes Node v18.15.0, React v17.0.2, and React-Router-DOM v5.3.4."

```
# npm audit report

xml2js  <0.5.0
Severity: high
xml2js is vulnerable to prototype pollution  - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-776f-qx25-q3cc
No fix available
node_modules/xml2js
  @azure/core-http  <=3.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of xml2js
  node_modules/@azure/core-http
  node_modules/@azure/storage-blob/node_modules/@azure/core-http
    @microsoft/teamsfx-api  *
    Depends on vulnerable versions of @azure/core-http
    node_modules/@microsoft/teamsfx-api
      @microsoft/teamsfx-core  *
      Depends on vulnerable versions of @microsoft/teamsfx-api
      Depends on vulnerable versions of office-addin-manifest
      Depends on vulnerable versions of xml2js
      node_modules/@microsoft/teamsfx-core
        @microsoft/teamsfx-cli  *
        Depends on vulnerable versions of @azure/core-http
        Depends on vulnerable versions of @microsoft/teamsfx-api
        Depends on vulnerable versions of @microsoft/teamsfx-core
        node_modules/@microsoft/teamsfx-cli
          office-addin-dev-settings  *
          Depends on vulnerable versions of @microsoft/teamsfx-cli
          Depends on vulnerable versions of office-addin-manifest
          node_modules/office-addin-dev-settings
  @azure/ms-rest-js  <=2.6.4
  Depends on vulnerable versions of xml2js
  node_modules/@azure/ms-rest-js
  office-addin-manifest  *
  Depends on vulnerable versions of xml2js
  node_modules/office-addin-manifest
    office-addin-debugging  *
    Depends on vulnerable versions of office-addin-dev-settings
    Depends on vulnerable versions of office-addin-manifest
    node_modules/office-addin-debugging

9 high severity vulnerabilities

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix

Some issues need review, and may require choosing
a different dependency.
```

I did not try to uninstall xml2js, as the question below suggests because I don't think that solution is relevant to the MS Office Add-in I'm developing.

[xml2js is vulnerable to prototype pollution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75975064/xml2js-is-vulnerable-to-prototype-pollution)

Comment: Have you tried to follow the link posted and implement the suggested solution there?

Comment: Thank you for your help. Yes, I'm now trying it after your comment. I used the instructions on the posted link. I don't have any vulnerability warning now. However, I wanted to know if the other dependencies indirectly tied to xml2js and relevant to the add-in will not create any problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Office web add-ins can be considered as regular NodeJS based web applications. So, the same security rules can be applied to web add-ins as well as web applications. The link posted provides possible solutions to the issue.